# How to set order of IQueryable query based on another list using linq in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-order-by, iqueryable

for example I have list of ItemIds as list1 in particular order and query has parameter ItemId. the query should be ordered based on order of ItemId in Iist1

I did try query = query.OrderBy(b => eventLists1.IndexOf(b.Id)); it throws exception as could not be translated

Comment: Incase null try following : OrderBy(b => (b.Id == null) ? 0 : eventLists1.IndexOf(b.Id))

Comment: Yeah, i think you might have the easiest time sorting this one on the client side. Do a ToList before you orderby. Also consider making a dictionary out of your eventsList, otherwise that IndexOf might run to O(n*n)

Comment: Since type of b.Id is int it won't be null, the result of the expression will always be false.

Comment: I do want to keep type of query as IQuerable<> only . If I place ToList befor orderBy type of query gets changed to IOrderedEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Queryable.OrderBy you need to pass `Expression<Func<int>>`. I agree that OrderBy can be excecuted locally, but for the sake of argument: yes you can write an expression:

```
private static Expression<Func<Test, int>> GetExpression(IEnumerable<int> listForOrdering)
{
    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test));
    var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, nameof(Test.ID));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Test, int>>(
        Expression.Switch(
            memberExpression,
            Expression.Constant(-1),
            listForOrdering.Select((idx, l) => Expression.SwitchCase(Expression.Constant(l), Expression.Constant(idx))).ToArray()),
        parameterExpression); 
}
```

E.g. `GetExpression(new[]{1,12,30})` creates the following expression:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[LinqProgram.Program+Test,System.Int32]>(LinqProgram.Program+Test $var1) {
.Switch ($var1.ID) {
.Case (1):
        0
.Case (12):
        1
.Case (30):
        2
.Default:
        -1
}
```

}